# Need help Accessing properties in Object Constructor Function (noLibs vanilla js only)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
let allLamps = [];      

// Object Constructor Function that will add new obj to array

function Object (serial, type, od, ol, arc) {
    this.serial = serial;
    this.type = type;
    this.od = od;
    this.ol = ol;
    this.arc = arc;
};       

const obj1 = new Object(1,"g51",75,95,46);
const obj2 = new Object(2,"g38",75,95,46);
const obj3 = new Object(3,"9k",57,67,27);

function push(obj) {
    allLamps.push(obj);
}

push(obj1);
push(obj2);
push(obj3);
```

1. So if Log the array allLamps to the console I get all my 
      objects:

   ```
   console.log(allLamps)
   ```
2. I want to access each property like:

   ```
   const getAll = allLamps.map(function(obj){
        return obj.serial;
   });
   ```
3. or

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i < allLamps.length; i++){
       return allLamps[i].serial;
   }
   ```
4. But it seems that I get undefined. Note I am still learning the basics. I know I'm doing something wrong. I appreciate any solution.
   Even if I do this:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < allLamps.length; i++ {
       return allLamps[i];
   }
   ```

I only get one of my objects, not all of them.

Comment: What is the question? Also, please don't name it `Object`, it will shadow the global `Object`.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. The name of the constructor initially was something else. But when I map through to get each property it returns undefined

Comment: Your code works. Is there any other code?

Comment: When I run it and I get undefined

Comment: try `const getAll = allLamps.map(obj => obj.serial);` and after that `console.log(getAll);`

Comment: Well yes, you are doing something wrong: you `return` from the middle of the loop. That's not the same as `return`ing from the callback function of the `map` call. If you use a loop, you need to manually put the elements in  the `getAll` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As literally defined array

```
const lamp = (serial, type, od, ol, arc) => ({serial, type, od, ol, arc});
const lamps = [lamp(1,"g51",75,95,46), lamp(2,"g38",75,95,46), lamp(3,"9k",57,67,27)];
```

As pushed array Items

```
const lamp = (serial, type, od, ol, arc) => lamps.push({serial, type, od, ol, arc});
const lamps = [];
lamp(1,"g51",75,95,46);
lamp(2,"g38",75,95,46); 
lamp(3,"9k",57,67,27);
```

or

```
const lamp = (serial, type, od, ol, arc) => ({serial, type, od, ol, arc});
const lamps = [];
lamps.push(lamp(1,"g51",75,95,46));
lamps.push(lamp(2,"g38",75,95,46)); 
lamps.push(lamp(3,"9k",57,67,27));
```

or

```
function Lamp (serial, type, od, ol, arc) {
    this.serial = serial;
    this.type = type;
    this.od = od;
    this.ol = ol;
    this.arc = arc;
};
const allLamps = [];
lamps.push(new Lamp(1,"g51",75,95,46));
lamps.push(new Lamp(2,"g38",75,95,46)); 
lamps.push(new Lamp(3,"9k",57,67,27));
```

or

```
const lamp = (serial, type, od, ol, arc) => ({serial, type, od, ol, arc});
const lamps = [
    [1,"g51",75,95,46],
    [2,"g38",75,95,46],
    [3,"9k",57,67,27]
 ].map(data => lamp(...data));
```

To name but a few